# How can I send requests from GitHub Pages without running into CORS?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

So I tried to host a little project I made in React.

[GitHub](https://github.com/mikolertesx/WeatherInfo)
[GitHub Pages](https://mikolertesx.github.io/WeatherInfo/)

But, everytime I try to send a request to MetaWeather, I get this back.
[image: Error]

I don't know what I should be doing different.
I used Axios, but even with Fetch the same thing happens.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: I can't read anything in that screenshot. It's just too tiny.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to enable CORS on Github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923328/is-there-a-way-to-enable-cors-on-github-pages)

Comment: I think you'll have to ask MetaWeather to add the CORS headers to their API, if they're happy for you to use it from web apps. I don't think this is something you can change in your code. The answer may well be that they don't want you do this, or don't support it.

Comment: @tadman Nope, if it was working like that, it should not be a problem, right?

Comment: @tadman Also sorry, I guess I got caught up and tired from doing this, I'm legitimately sorry.

Comment: @Rup Looks like that's the case. But there's no way to know before hand, right?

Comment: You can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ but remember it should be enabled from there side also.

Comment: At the end I used your solution @VaibhavRai, thank you!

Comment: @MiguelAngelGuerreroSalinas glad it helped you, I am adding it as an answer then :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ but remember it should be enabled from there side also